# What would x=2's probability be?

Tags: probability

Suppose you are playing darts where you get three throws. Let X be the number of times you hit a bullseye and have the following distribution table:
[hitting a dartboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbdJV.png)
.

What would x=2's probability be?

This is a binomial distribution question.

Comment: What are your attempts at solving this?

Comment: Probabilities must add to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier than it looks.

Note that there are only $3$ throws, therefore a maximum of $3$ possible bullseyes. All possible outcomes' probabilities must add up to $1$.
Therefore, we have:
$$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)=1$$
Plug in the values you have for each probability, and solve for $P(X=2)$.

Answer (score 0):

For Probability that it hits 2 times i.e when X=2 is

P(X=2) = 3 C (2) (probability that it hits right)^2 * (1-Probability that it hits right)^1